# Understanding super keyword for abstract classes

Tags: java, super

Consider the following class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public abstract String m();

    public AbstractClass get(){
        return new AbstractClass() {

            @Override
            public String m() {
                return "Anonymous " + super.m(); //1, Compile-time erro
            }
        };
    }

}
```

It's not clear why such using of `super` is prohibited. At `//1`, the following error is occured

```
Cannot directly invoke the abstract method m() for the type AbstractClass
```

So, I consulted the [JLS 15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2) and didn't find the restriction preventing such code from being compiled. Here they are:

1. Obviously

> It is a compile-time error if the forms using the keyword super appear
>   in the declaration of class Object, since Object has no superclass.

2. Since it's impossible to have an instance of `AbstractClass`, but only one of its ***concrete*** subclasses, the following seems to me valid as well:

> The forms using the keyword super are valid only in an instance
>   method, instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of
>   an instance variable of a class. If they appear anywhere else, a
>   compile-time error occurs.

3. Not the case.

> It is a compile-time error if the current class is not an inner class
>   of class T or T itself.

Of course, I can use `AbstractClass.this.m()`, but this is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Why would you want to call `super.m()` here? That method is not implemented in `AbstractClass`, so it makes no sense to try to call it.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, it's not. But as I already said it implemented in a conrete class. We can't have an instance of the `AbstractClass` itself, but only one of its subclasses.

Comment: Note that `super.m()` does not call the `m` that's overridden in the anonymous subclass. You're telling Java to explicitly call the implementation in the superclass. Since the method is abstract in the superclass, it can't be called. (What do you expect `super.m()` to do?).

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that #15.11.2 isn't the only applicable rule? Is there something in the JLS that allows you to call abstract methods? What's the question here?

Comment: @Jesper Not exactly clear. From [JLS 15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2) _The form super.Identifier refers to the field named Identifier of the **current object**, but with the **current object** viewed as an instance of the superclass of the current class._ The current object here is an instance of one of the abstract class subclasses, so I still don't see any problem... What did I miss?

Comment: So, if I understood what in the JLS correctly. We're only concerned about the _current object **runtime** type_.

Comment: If you call a method using `super`, then the normal polymorphism rules for finding which method to call do not apply. It's going to look explicitly in the superclass, and it's not going to call the overridden version of the method in a subclass (JLS 15.12.1).

Comment: @Jesper Yes, now I see, thank you. _If the form is super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier, then the name of the method is the Identifier and the class to be searched is the superclass of the class **whose declaration contains the method invocation**._

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The super keyword does not work here because `AbstractClass.m()` has been declared abstract, and therefore there is no suitable implementation of it on the parent of the inner class.  Remember that inner classes do not extend the outer class (even if it is of the same type), they include a reference to it instead.

However when working from an inner class calling to the outer class (which is what I believe you meant to do here) then use the following syntax `AbstractClass.this.m()`.

The following will compile and work as intended.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public abstract String m();

    public AbstractClass get(){
        return new AbstractClass() {

            @Override
            public String m() {
                return "Anonymous " + AbstractClass.this.m(); 
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note:  if you hold on to the AbstractClass that was returned by get(), don't forget that it will still be holding a reference to the original AbstractClass that you called get() against.   This becomes important if you drop the reference to that original object and expect it to get GC'd... it won't.  This is a common gotcha that causes unexpected memory leaks.

Comment: So, the note _If the form is super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier, then the name of the method is the Identifier and the class to be searched is the superclass of the class whose declaration contains the method invocation._ is relevant here as well, isn't?

Comment: @St.Antario  yes.  The super keyword means 'scan the object hierarchy of the current object for the method'.    In your example there are two objects of type 'AbstractClass', and a third is implied (but not included) hence the confusion.   The three are, 1) the AbstractClass itself, 2) the anonymous inner class created within get() and 3) the subclass of AbstractClass that would be needed in order to call get() at all.   The inner class one extends AbstractClass directly, and thus scanning its parent for m() will find the abstract declaration of m() with no implementation.

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know, the compiler tries to use static binding when using `super.m();`. As there is no method `super.m();` since it is abstract the compiler already complains at compile time.

Static binding in Java means that the methods are resolved during compile time while dynamic binding occurs during runtime when using a method which could be override by several subclasses.